# crazy characters when saving XML? &#x1F;

Tags: xml, vb.net, textbox

I have a input field/textbox and basicly the user presses a button to save the content of edittextbox.text to a stringparameter

`&#x1F;`

are the charaters thats being saved.. so my question is where do they come from and how can i parse these out before saveing XML content?

when i debugg my textbox it shows up as a regular string without and strange characters so i cant use string.replace()

```
Dim leftXML As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(MyLib.ComputerSettings))
Dim myxml As System.IO.TextWriter = New IO.StreamWriter(SavePath)
leftXML.Serialize(myxml, CmpSettings)
myxml.Flush()
myxml.Close()
```

above code for XML save. object MyLib.ComputerSettings has a regular string parameter called Init

Answer (score 2):

`&#x1f;` is an Unicode Hex Character: ['INFORMATION SEPARATOR ONE' (U+001F)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f/index.htm). (This was also in ASCII at 0x1F: [`US`, the "Unit Separator"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_separator).)

You're probably encoding some separator in your serialization process.